# I can't add items to cart in a shopping app by redux in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, shopping-cart

I am trying to create a simple shopping app, I use redux and react-navigation in my project.

There is a `Home`screen, `Books` screen and `Cart`screen.

I've imported items via a simple array named`books` into `Books` screen

**This is the codes into `Books` screen:**

```
import { useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import { addSomething} from '../actions';
import { books } from '../data/fakedata';




const Books = (props) => {

  const { navigation } = props;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();


const bookProduct=(books)=>{

return books.map((item, index)=>{

return(
  <TouchableOpacity 
  key={index}
  onPress={()=>dispatch(addSomething(books))}
  >
<Text style={{color:'white'}}>{item.name}- {item.price}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>

)})}


return (
      <View >
              {bookProduct(books)}
      </View> )}
```

**This the `action` file:**

```
export const addSomething = (books) => {

    return (dispatch) => {

        dispatch({
            type: 'ADD',
            payload: books
        })

    }


}
export const removeSomething = (books) => {

    return (dispatch) => {

        dispatch({
            type: 'REMOVE',
            payload: books
        })

    }


}
```

**This is the `Header` component into `Books` screen which hold an state and would be updated after each click on items:**

```
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';


const Header =(props)=>{

 const {navigation }=props;
 const counter=useSelector(state=>state.cardR.counter);

return(
<Fragment>


<Icon onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('Cart')}  />

<Text>{counter}</Text>

</Fragment>
)}
```

**This is the `reducer` file:**

```
const initialState={
counter:0,
item:''

}

export default (state=initialState, action)=>{

switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD':
        return {counter:state.counter+1,item:action.payload}
        break;
    case 'REMOVE':

         return something else

        break;

    default:
        return state;
}}
```

**This is `Combinereducer` file:**:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import cartReducer from './cartReducer';
import visibleReducer from './visibleReducer';


export default combineReducers({

cartR:cartReducer,
visibleR:visibleReducer 


})
```

**And this is the `store` file:**

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const initialState={

    cardR:{counter:0, object:''},
    visibleR:{visible:false}

}


export const store = createStore(reducers, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk) );
```

**My problem:**

I can update state `{counter}` in header when user click on a item in ``` Books`` screen but i need to add items into ```cart``` screen at the same time with that click, but it doesn't happen

I would be grateful if you help me to solve it out

Answer (score 0):

```
//item, not books
onPress={()=>dispatch(addSomething(item))}
```

Also you can remove initialState from

```
export const store = createStore(reducers, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk) );
```

Cause you are setting up initialState for each reducer directly

Updated code for `reducer` file

```
const initialState={
counter:0,
items: [],

}

export default (state=initialState, action)=>{

switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD':
        return {counter:state.counter+1, items: [...state.items, action.payload.item]}}
        break;
    case 'REMOVE':

         return something else

        break;

    default:
        return state;
}}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I changed my code to what you said but it didn't work, I can't remove ```initialState``` from ```const store``` because i am using ```combineReducer``` and i need to import ```initialState```  again in ```store``` I changed reducer to this: ```{counter:state.counter+1, items: [...state.items, action.payload.item]}}``` but i am getting this error when i click on items in ```Books``` screen : Type error: invalid attempt to spread not iterable instance```

Comment: so in this case try to change this part of the store file
```
const initialState={

    cardR:{counter:0, object:''"},
    visibleR:{visible:false}

}
```
to
```
const initialState={

    cardR:{counter:0, items: []},
    visibleR:{visible:false}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time buddy, but issue is persisting, I don't see any error anymore but 
 book items don't add to ```cart``` screen, I should say ```count``` is updating in ```Header```with each click without any problem, Do you have any idea?